# Move down Cells because the Data has been Over write in Excel

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

Good Afternoon

I have an Excel File this is what it looks.

[image]

and I have a VB.Net Program that looks like this.

[image]

Now after clicking the `Print Transmittal Form` the data from Datagridview will transfer into the Excel Format that I created but theres something wrong and here is the output.

[image]

The data overwrite this part.

[image]

How can I prevent that? Instead of over writing the cells the overwritten part will move down based on how many data on datagridview.

Here is my code.

```
   If DataGridView1.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Nothing to Export")
        Else
            Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
            Dim ExcelSheet As Object
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1
            Dim total As Double = 0

            ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            ExcelBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open("c:\SR Transmittal.xlsx")
            ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets("Transmittal Form")
            rowIndex += 11
            With ExcelSheet
                For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                    Dim columnIndex As Integer = 0
                    Do Until columnIndex
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 2).Value = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 3).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 4).Value = DataGridView1.Item("RequestedQty", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 5).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 6).Value = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 7).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value.ToString
                        ExcelSheet.Cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 8).Value = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value.ToString
                        .cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 4).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
                        .cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 6).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
                        .cells(i + 12, columnIndex + 7).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
                        columnIndex += rowIndex
                        .Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit()
                        .Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.Font.Size = 9
                    Loop

                Next

            End With
            ExcelApp.Visible = True
            ExcelSheet = Nothing
            ExcelBook = Nothing
            ExcelApp = Nothing
        End If
```

TYSM for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently worked on something similar, I achieved it by inserting a new row prior to poplulating with data. For you it would look something like:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    oSheet.Range(oSheet.Cells(i + 12, 2), oSheet.Cells(i + 12, 8)).Insert(Shift:=Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)
    '... add row data
```

Also, FWIW, is the use of `columnIndex` and its `Do Until` entirely redundant? The loop will only ever run once (prior to having 12 (`rowIndex`) added to it?

Comment: Noted on that sir TY

Comment: @NyxAssasin You're welcome! Does the proposed code work? If so I'd appreciate the answer being marked as correct.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Hope to see you again when i had a concern in excel because that`s one of my problems today TYSM